# How can I check if an iOS device has the vibration in Unity?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, hardware, vibration

I've been searching for an answer but I can't find it anywhere.

I was basically looking for a way to detect through code if the iOS device has the vibration hardware or not in Unity Engine.
I know that I can check the device type through the `DeviceGeneration` properties and exclude Tablets or some iPods, but I was looking for a more general and logic way to approach to this problem.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UnityEngine namespace contains [SystemInfo.supportsVibration](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-supportsVibration.html). This property return true, if running device support vibration.